# Google cloud messaging endpoint register fails locally

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I used [Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) using eclipse, and changed the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to true. I searched for  the error and seemed like adding --address=0.0.0.0  before port in the web application run configurations would make it work, however it didn't, so any help?

Logcat

```
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120): Exception received when attempting to register with server at http://10.0.2.2:8888/_ah/api/
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120): {
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):   "code" : 503,
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):   "errors" : [ {
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):     "domain" : "global",
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):     "message" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.imagine.EMF",
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):     "reason" : "backendError"
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):   } ],
04-01 19:43:27.524: E/com.imagine.GCMIntentService(2120):   "message" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.imagine.EMF"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the information provided is less so its difficult ot tell the actual cause of error.

Secondly, I think you are referring to an old doc which uses Eclispe. I would recommend using Android Studio which is now Google's official IDE and follow the instruction in this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/mobile/messaging/add_module).

This is relatively easy as the work around of configuring and setting things up is cut to half.

For the sample code refer [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints).

Comment: I found the error cause I was using java SDK 1.8 while Appengine works with 1.7. However I will check your link as I have no experience dealing with servers and would rather deal with something deploy ready for my project

Comment: I just had some free time and decided to check your tutorial. Definitely simple and saving time! However is the Server deploy ready? I'm trying to be to only post as an admin